# How to retrieve two or more values from same column and show in table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve three values they are: Ativos, Inativos and Indimplentes.     How to do that?

My current code.

```
$kvp= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)  
AS status FROM tb_clientes WHERE status ='Ativo'") or die (mysql_error() );
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS status FROM tb_clientes WHERE status IN('Ativo', ' Inativos', 'Indimplentes')

Comment: My colummn called status and i have this values stored in db ativo, inativo and inadimplentes. It's easy to echo this values ativos....?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want a count for wherever the status is either of those, use `IN` or `WHERE x OR x OR x`

`IN` is supposedly more efficient than using `WHERE OR` - although if your table is fairly small in size, and you're only using these 3 conditions - it probably won't be noticeable.

E.g.

`WHERE status = 'Ativo' OR status = 'Inativos' OR status = 'Indimplentes'`

`WHERE status IN ('Ativo','Inativos','Indimplentes')`

Comment: Do you have a citation for `IN` being less efficient than `WHERE OR`?

Comment: @Styphon I worded it backwards. I was about to provide a citation for `IN` being more efficient, then I realised what I'd done.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `IN` condition

```
$kvp= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)
AS status FROM tb_clientes WHERE status IN('Ativo','Inativo','Indimplente')") or die (mysql_error() );
```

You can continue to add values, by comma separating them, making sure to wrap strings in quotes.

Please double check the names I have put as in your question you mention `Ativos`, but in your code you put `Ativo`. I have presumed the names from this.

**Update**

Here is an example of how to achieve what you need.

```
$link = mysql_connect('dbhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpass'); //replace dbhost,dbuser and db pass with your details

$selected = mysql_select_db("dbname",$link) or die("Could not select dbname"); //Put your database name in here replacing dbname

$kvp = mysql_query("SELECT status, count(1) as count FROM tb_clientes GROUP BY status") or die (mysql_error());

echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>Status</td><td>Count</td></tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($kvp)) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['status'] . '</td><td>' . $row['count'] . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Invalid `WHERE` clause

Comment: @DavidNewcomb rather than downvoting, why not edit and fix such a simple mistake?

Comment: Yes i know. It's Ativo only. Thanks for ur reply. Now how to echo all this values? They are stored in db on colummn status.

Comment: @user3232406 "SELECT COUNT(*)" will only fetch how many rows there are that match the where clause, not any data that is in the rows.

Comment: @user3232406 what field from the database do you wish to echo? The status?

Comment: I would end up fixing 1000s of silly mistakes made by people rushing to be the first to answer. Take your time to provide a better answer. At least I gave a reason for my downvote, most people don't.

Comment: I want to show the values stored in status column. There are only three values there, ativo, inativos and inadimplentes. Sorry for bad explanation. I'm trying to be better.

Comment: The field status where the values are stored.

Comment: @user3232406 I have included in my answer how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You use `IN`

```
 $kvp= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)
 AS status FROM tb_clientes WHERE status IN('Ativo', 'Inativos', 'Indimplentes')") or die (mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$kvp= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS status FROM tb_clientes WHERE status IN('Ativo', Inativos, ") or die (mysql_error() );
```

With IN you can specify differents values.

Comment: Ok get the point. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a separate count for each status.

```
SELECT status, count(1)
FROM tb_clientes
GROUP BY status
```

Gives:

```
+--------------+----------+
| status       | count(1) |
+--------------+----------+
| Ativos       |      178 |
| Inativos     |      282 |
| Indimplentes |        2 |
+--------------+----------+
```

If you would like to do it in 1 SQL command then try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status='Ativos',1,0))
    ,SUM(IF(status='Inativos',1,0))
    ,SUM(IF(status='Indimplentes',1,0))
    FROM tb_clientes;
```

Gives:

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| SUM(IF(status='Ativos',1,0)) | SUM(IF(status='Inativos',1,0)) | SUM(IF(status='Indimplentes',1,0)) |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|                         178  |                            282 |                                  2 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Status dos Clientes:
Clientes Ativos: 178
Clientes Inativos: 282
Inadimplentes: 2
This is i want to echo on my table. Right now i have it work but i have to create each select for each status.

Comment: I want to show the values stored in status column. There are only three values there, ativo, inativos and inadimplentes. Sorry for bad explanation. I'm trying to be better.